# Can I let use login to access their AWS S3 objects just like let user login to access your Google Drive items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth

I want to know if it's possible and how to let user login and grant to access their AWS S3 objects just like let user login to access your Google Drive items.

For Google, I create an App and use it along with Google auth to let user login and grant permission, then I can get access token to behalf the user to access their Google Drive items.

Any reference, direction etc. is welcome,

Thanks in advance,

Henry

I search and read AWS SDK and Login with Amazon, seems not works. Or I missed the full flow to get the work done :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no capability to let other people "login" like you.

However, if you wish to share a private objects stored in Amazon S3, you can create an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3.

You would need to programmatically generate the URL and provide it to the other people.

This is similar to show you can go into Dropbox or Google Docs and create a "View only" link to a file.